# How do I run the same exact command, N number of times in parallel using GNU parallel?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, gnu

I want to execute a python script X times with the same arguments in parallel, but I don't know how to accomplish this with GNU parallel.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is the equivalent of

> parallel 'python3 script.py' ::: file1 file1 file1 ... file1

without having to manually type the filename X times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the *right* way to do it, but you could generate *N* dummy arguments (using `seq` for example) and then tell `parallel` to read but not insert them using `-N0` (making the real argument part of the command string).

Ex. for *N = 5*:

```
$ seq 1 5 | parallel --dryrun -N0  python3 script.py file1 :::
python3 script.py file1 
python3 script.py file1 
python3 script.py file1 
python3 script.py file1 
python3 script.py file1
```

Comment: Normally you would leave out the ::: too.